# WADL request representation parameter with nested values (e.g. foo[bar]=baz)

Tags: xml, wadl, apigee

How can I define a request representation parameter that has a nested value?

```
<param name="foo[bar]" required="true" type="xsd:string" style="query" default="baz">
```

Results in "string value 'foo[bar]' does not match pattern for xs:NMTOKEN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it, per http://support.apigee.com/apigee/topics/how_do_i_define_a_request_representation_with_nested_values_e_g_foo_bar_baz

```
<request>
  <representation>
    <param name="foo_bar" apigee:paramName="foo[bar]" required="true" type="xsd:string" style="query" default="baz">
  </representation>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a square bracket in an apigee:paramName, you should use the numeric entity like so:

`apigee:paramName="foo&#091;bar&#093;"​`

Otherwise the brackets may not appear correctly.